# Rails active record dynamic finders, creators etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to learn Rails and I am currently reading on active record. I am trying to understand the many different dynamic finders and ways you can create objects however I do not find a place where all the different combinations are listed. Where do I find this? I have tried reading in three different books but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful: http://www.kesava.me/blog/2011/08/15/dynamic-finders/. The different combinations are generated by `method_missing`, so they are not listed explicitly anywhere in the Rails codebase.

Also, you might find this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/2-dynamic-find-by-methods) useful too.

Comment: Yes, I know they are dynamically made but there must be a pattern that it follows.

Comment: `User.find_by_attr1_attr2_attr_3(attr1_val, attr2_val, attr3_val)`. Is this the pattern you are talking about?

Comment: Not only, you have all the different ways you can create objects in associations, find objects in a particular association etc. I can't see where this is listed.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html, really helpful information